# Codable Custom Enum Types

Tags: swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, model, codable

I have a model that is an enumeration of structs.  I need to conform this enum to `Codable`.

```
import Foundation

enum Post: Codable {

    case textPost(TextPost)
    case imagePost(ImagePost)
    case videoPost(VideoPost)

    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {

    }

    func encode(to encoder: Encoder) throws {

    }
}

struct TextPost: Codable {
    let documentID: String
    let createdAt: Int
    let organization: Organization
    let title: String
    let description: String
    let commentTotal: Int
}

struct ImagePost: Codable {
    let documentID: String
    let createdAt: Int
    let organization: Organization
    let title: String
    let description: String
    let commentTotal: Int
    let imageURL: String
}

struct VideoPost: Codable {
    let documentID: String
    let createdAt: Int
    let organization: Organization
    let title: String
    let description: String
    let commentTotal: Int
    let videoURL: String
}
```

I am using Firestore from Firebase to store and retrieve data.

Previously when using simple `struct`s I was using the following extension to decode;

```
extension QueryDocumentSnapshot {

    func decode() -> [String: Any] {
        var data = self.data()
        data["documentID"] = documentID
        return data
    }
}

extension JSONDecoder {
    func decodeQuery<T>(_ type: T.Type, fromJSONObject object: Any) throws -> T where T: Decodable {
        return try decode(T.self, from: try JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: object, options: []))
    }
}
```

I was calling this like:

```
func retrievePosts(success: @escaping([Post]) -> ()) {
    var posts = [Post]()
    reference(to: .posts).getDocuments { (snapshot, error) in
        if error != nil {
            print(error as Any)
            return
        } else {
            guard let snapshotDocuments = snapshot?.documents else { return }
            for snapshot in snapshotDocuments {
                if let post = try? JSONDecoder().decodeQuery(Post.self, fromJSONObject: snapshot.decode()) {
                    posts.append(post)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

However, this doesn't work on `enum`s

Comment: Why don't you simply add a post type to your struct and create a single one instead of 3 of them practically identicals

Comment: @LeoDabus I'll be adding other post items later. They may be much different from the three listed here.

Comment: Still they are all a post. Create optional properties for those and check the kind when dealing with them. `struct Post: Codable {
    enum Kind: String, Codable {
        case text, image, video
    }

    let id: String
    let createdAt: Date
    let organization: Organization
    let title: String
    let description: String
    let commentTotal: Int
    let imageURL: URL?
    let videoURL: URL?
}

struct Organization: Codable {}`

Comment: @LeoDabus this doesn't give me access to switch the kind when it comes to cellForRowAt. so I can return a specific cell for each type.

Comment: I forgot to add the kind property along with the enumeration

Comment: `struct Post: Codable {
    enum Kind: String, Codable {
        case text, image, video
    }
    let id: String
    let kind: Kind
    let createdAt: Date
    let organization: Organization
    let title: String
    let description: String
    let commentTotal: Int
    let imageURL: URL?
    let videoURL: URL?
}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to:

1. add the `CodingKeys` enum
2. implement `init(from:)`
3. implement `encode(to:)`
4. add an `Error` enum

Here's the code:

```
enum Post: Codable {

    case textPost(TextPost)
    case imagePost(ImagePost)
    case videoPost(VideoPost)

    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let values = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)

        if let value = try? values.decode(TextPost.self, forKey: .textPost) {
            self = .textPost(value)
            return
        }
        if let value = try? values.decode(ImagePost.self, forKey: .imagePost) {
            self = .imagePost(value)
            return
        }
        if let value = try? values.decode(VideoPost.self, forKey: .videoPost) {
            self = .videoPost(value)
            return
        }

        throw Error.invalidData
    }

    func encode(to encoder: Encoder) throws {
        var container = encoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        switch self {
        case .textPost(let value):
            try container.encode(value, forKey: .textPost)
        case .imagePost(let value):
            try container.encode(value, forKey: .imagePost)
        case .videoPost(let value):
            try container.encode(value, forKey: .videoPost)
        }
    }

    private enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case textPost
        case imagePost
        case videoPost
    }

    enum Error: Swift.Error {
        case invalidData
    }
}
```

### Test

I will use this simplified version of your `TextPost` struct.

```
do {
    let post = Post.imagePost(ImagePost(documentID: "123"))
    let data = try JSONEncoder().encode(post)
    let decodedPost = try JSONDecoder().decode(Post.self, from: data)
    print(decodedPost)
} catch {
    print(error)
}
```

Result:

```
imagePost(ImagePost(documentID: "123"))
```

Comment: Thanks @Luca when implementing this to get the posts from Firestore it is not decoding into an array of posts.  i.e. using this.  Do I need a different approach?

for snapshot in snapshotDocuments {
                if let post = try? JSONDecoder().decodeQuery(Post.self, fromJSONObject: snapshot.decode()) {
                    posts.append(post)
                }
            }

Comment: Try replacing Post.self with [Post].self

Comment: that doesn't work unfortunately.  I've wrapped decoding in a 'do-try-catch' block, however, getting back invalidData error.